# PHP RexExp match and substitute

Tags: php, regex

I am testing RegExp with online regexr.com tool. I will test string with multiple cases, but I can't get substitution to work.

RexEx for matching string is:

```
/^[0-9]{1,3}[0-9]{6,7}$/
```

Which matches local mobile number in my country like this:

**0921234567**

But then I want to substitute number in this way: add "+" sign, add my country code "123", add "." sign, and then finaly, add matched number with stripped leading zero.

Final number will be:

**+385.921234567**

I have basic idea to insert matched string, but I am not sure how prepend characters, and strip zero from matched string in following substitution pattern:

```
\+$&\n\t
```

I will use PHP preg_replace function.

EDIT:

As someone mentioned wisely, there is posibility that there will be one, two or none of zeros, but I will create separate test cases with regex just testing number of zeroes. Doing so in one regex seems to complicated for now.

Possible numbers will be:

**0921234567**
**00111921234567**

Where 111 is country code. I know that some country codes consist of 2 or 3 digits, but I will create special cases, for most country codes.

Comment: `^[0-9]{1,3}[0-9]{6,7}$` is equivalent to `^[0-9]{7,10}$`.

Comment: What would be the expected output for `00111921234567`

Comment: Ok, I see you accepted an answer, although I'd use a [2 step solution](https://ideone.com/ekA2hq).

Comment: @vks, good question. I have to strip all zeroes from begining.

Comment: @AlanKis so `00111921234567` should turn into `+385111921234567` ?????//

Comment: @vks, yes. Maybe I was unclear. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @AlanKis the answer u acccepted does not do that https://regex101.com/r/cJ6zQ3/27

Comment: Yes, you are correct. That's due to character number limit, that's why I added EDIT. I will create cases, checking for country code at start, and then strip zeroes.

Comment: @AlanKis You can just remove last range restriction and use: `$str = preg_replace('~^0*(\d{7,})$~', '+385.$1', $str);`. [See this demo](https://regex101.com/r/cJ6zQ3/28)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `preg_replace` to strip optional zeroes from start of your mobile #:

```
$str = preg_replace('~^0*(\d{7,9})$~', '+385.$1', $str);
```

Comment: This answer fits my question best. There is possibility that there will be one, two or none of zeros.

Comment: Anubhava, *still* kicking arse, You deserve a t-shirt.

Comment: What does tilde mean here in pattern?

Comment: PHP allows any char to be used as regex delimiter. `/` or `~` or `#` are widely used as delimiters.

Answer (score 2):

```
^[0-9]([0-9]{1,2}[0-9]{6,7})$
```

You just need to add `groups`.Replace by `+385.$1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cJ6zQ3/22

```
$re = "/^[0-9]([0-9]{1,2}[0-9]{6,7})$/m"; 
$str = "0921234567\n"; 
$subst = "+385.$1"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: What if there are more than 1 zero at the beginning? Or no zero at all? If input is `0021234567`, the output is `+385.021234567`. A zero is still there. I am not sure if that is expected.

Comment: @stribizhev then OP's regex will not match it .

Comment: Why `[0-9]` instead of just `0` at the beginning of the regex? Probably better if the regex doesn't match if the first digit isn't a zero.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a 2-step solution:

1. Check if we match the main regex
2. Replace the number by pre-pending `+` + `country code` + `.` + `number without leading zeros`.

[PHP code](https://ideone.com/ekA2hq):

```
$re = "/^[0-9]{7,10}$/"; 
$str = "0921234567"; 
if (preg_match($re, $str, $match)) {
    echo "+385." . preg_replace('/^0+/', '', $match[0]);
}
```

Note that splitting out character class in your regex pattern makes no sense when not using capture groups. `^[0-9]{7,10}$` is the same then as `^[0-9]{1,3}[0-9]{6,7}$`, meaning *match 7 to 10 digits from start to end of the string*.

Leading zeros are easily trimmed from the start with `/^0+/` regex.